# How do you approach potential harassment witnesses?

Tags: professionalism, colleagues, harassment

I was harassed by my direct supervisor at my old company.

The harassement was all verbal and there were potential witnesses but few direct. For example, there were people within hearing distance/sitting in the next cubicle of the verbal abuse but it's not clear to me if they were paying attention.

Some of the incidences where a while ago. I'll be needing to ask them if they remember the incidences.

I'm guessing it's best to ask for their personal email and then email them the incidences and if they might remember any of them. Obviously, this is a loaded and sesitive topic.

Is it best to make a first quick casual contact? Just send them an email saying hello would you like to keep in touch although it does sound awkward.

Next ask them if they remember some incidences?

Edit: I have already filed a lawsuit against the company. I don't have a lawyer I'm going it on my own.

Comment: Are you contemplating legal action?  Filing a complaint with HR?  Is there a reason that you are approaching these people yourself rather than just providing the names to HR/ your lawyer and letting them approach the potential witnesses?

Comment: *A man who is his own lawyer has a fool for a client* -- [adage, early 19th century](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/a-man-who-is-his-own-lawyer-has-a-fool-for-a-client.html).

Answer (score 8):

Get a lawyer, have them contact the people for you. This sounds too vague and unpromising to win on your own (if at all) especially since it's in the past and you have another court case against the company.

Sending someone an email to their company email address while you're in the process of suing the company and asking for them to remember details so you can sue one of their colleagues isn't a great idea. There would likely be some resistance and it would be very easy for the company to find out which might end with disciplinary action for the person you're contacting. Which in turn would not make them eager to bolster your case.

Sending them a personal email is slightly better but still unlikely to be taken well. If they help you they endanger themselves however mildly. If it was me I would be unhappy that you even contacted me and involved me with your problems.